# can someone explain the rule for using which and that

Tags: grammar

What is the correct grammar for use of the words, which and that?

Answer (score 0):

By usage, there is no difference between the function of which and that as relative pronouns.  Both formal and informal written and spoken English use which and that interchangeably (and have done so for centuries) and so the rule that governs their use is more of a guideline than a law.

- *that* is used to introduce a *restrictive clause*, that is to say, a clause with a meaning that is essential to the sentence.
- *which* is used to introduce a *nonrestrictive clause*, or one whose meaning adds to a sentence but which is not essential to its meaning (see what I did there?).

Comment: Not entirely true, in which [sic] there is a definite difference between the grammar of these words when they ***follow*** a preposition.